# Find in array of jsons postgres typeORM node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

### Issue Description

@Entity({name: 'reports'})
export class Report extends BaseEntity {

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
public id: number;

@Column({name: 'dates_parsed', type: 'jsonb'})
public datesParsed: any;
```

}

[image]

I want to find all reports where day > 3.

Using SQL in PgAdmin I am able to find correct data using the next queries

```
SELECT  r.id, p ->> 'day' as day
FROM   "reports" r, jsonb_array_elements(r.dates_parsed) p
where (p->>'day')::int > 3
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM "reports" r
WHERE r.id IN (SELECT  t.id
FROM   "reports" t, jsonb_array_elements(t.dates_parsed) p
where (p->>'day')::int > 3)
```

We are not able use `jsonb_array_elements` in from it expects entityTarget

```
    const qb = this.createQueryBuilder(`reports`)
        .where(qb2 => {
            const subQuery = qb.subQuery()
                .select('report.id')
                .from(Report, 'report')
                .from('jsonb_array_elements(report.dates_parsed)', 'dates')
                .where(`(dates->>'day')::int > 3`)
                .getQuery();
            return `reports IN ` + subQuery;
        });
```

We can't  create a query like this, because `parsed` is invisible in **where**

```
    const qb = this.createQueryBuilder(`reports`);
    qb.where(qb2 => {
        const subQuery = qb.subQuery()
            .select('report.id')
            .select('jsonb_array_elements(report.dates_parsed)', 'parsed')
            .from(Report, 'report')
            .where(`(parsed->>'day')::int > 3`)
            .getQuery();
        return `reports IN ` + subQuery;
    });
```

How to create a query using typeorm if I want to find data in my table. Where day equals 5

[ {
"id": "1",
"datesParsed": [
{
"day": 6
},
{
"day": 3
}
],
"id": "2",
"datesParsed": [
{
"day": 10
},
{
"day": 5
}
],
]

#### My Environment

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | macos |
| Node.js version | v14.5 |
| Typescript version | v4.0.3 |
| TypeORM version | v0.2.28 |

#### Additional Context

#### Relevant Database Driver(s)

- [ ] `aurora-data-api`
- [ ] `aurora-data-api-pg`
- [ ] `better-sqlite3`
- [ ] `cockroachdb`
- [ ] `cordova`
- [ ] `expo`
- [ ] `mongodb`
- [ ] `mysql`
- [ ] `nativescript`
- [ ] `oracle`
- [x] `postgres`
- [ ] `react-native`
- [ ] `sap`
- [ ] `sqlite`
- [ ] `sqlite-abstract`
- [ ] `sqljs`
- [ ] `sqlserver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example of how to resolve it

```
const qb = this.createQueryBuilder(`reports`);
 
qb.andWhere((`reports.id IN (SELECT  t.id FROM   "reports" t, jsonb_array_elements(t.dates_parsed) p where (p->>'day')::int = 5)`));
```